# Remapping Firebase JSON data in React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase, react-native

EDIT: I've had to change this question after finding out more about my inital issue.

The have data that looks like this:

```
{
  "-fdsdsghdfsgsfdfdgfd" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  },
  "-dsdgfrdhfdgfdgdgfd" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  },
  "-Lv3cEcoiJ1wtajIzPyy" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  }
}
```

Imported like this
`import waypoint from '../data/jobdata.json';`

Is it easily possible to remap the data to follow this form...

```
const waypoint = [
    {latitude: -37.830331, longitude: 144.9923426, found: false },
    {latitude: -37.830331, longitude: 144.9923426, found: false },
    {latitude: -37.830331, longitude: 144.9923426, found: false }
];
```

I just don't know React Native well enough to understand how to fix this.

I'm not looking to get the data from Firebase let's just assume it's a JSON file like above.

Thanks

Comment: try `Object.values(data).map(item => <Component />)`

Comment: @ThomasByy you want to iterate all object or single object because your keys are same that's why it's avoiding all objects

Comment: Hi sorry, I believe your information might have helped but I have run into a larger issue that simply requires the data to look slightly different. I have edited the question with what I now realise I need instead. Sorry and thanks

Comment: im confused , so you want to convert "-Lv3cEcoiJ1wtajIzPyy" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  }, into

const waypoint = [
    {latitude: -37.827047, longitude: 144.991987, found: false },
    {latitude: -37.828288, longitude: 144.991708, found: false },
    {latitude: -37.826503, longitude: 144.995964, found: false },
    {latitude: -37.826835, longitude: 144.992808, found: false },
    {latitude: -37.825441, longitude: 144.991112, found: false }
]; 

RIGHt?

Comment: @ThomasByy can you explain me little more? why duplicate keys are there and all the object having same values so why you want to repeat same object in array.

Comment: Just the structure. I want to reassign the imported waypoint into another variable, say waypoint2, but with the new structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have unique object keys for every child object, here is the solution below. Now you can iterate through `Object.values(data)`

```js
let data = {
  "First" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  },
  "Second" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  },
  "Third" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have duplicate keys then `Object.values` will discard duplicates.

```js
let data = {
  "-Lv3cEcoiJ1wtajIzPyy" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  },
  "-Lv3cEcoiJ1wtajIzPyy" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  },
  "-Lv3cEcoiJ1wtajIzPyy" : {
    "latitude" : -37.830331,
    "longitude" : 144.9923426,
    "found" : false
  }
}
let output = Object.values(data);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Can you explain how you get the last one in the new array? `Object.values(waypoints)[Object.values(waypoints).length]` is my dumb attempt.

Answer (score 1):

since you are fetching it from firebase i think the key should be unique. So you can use the below way to achieve the data.

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const obj = {
  "-Lv3cEcoiJ1wtajIzPyy": {
    "latitude": -37.830331,
    "longitude": 144.9923426,
    "found": false
  }
}

const transformed = Object.values(obj)

console.log(transformed)
```